# pip-compile with --index-url option delivers pinned package versions that are not on passed package index

Tags: python, pip-tools

We are using `pip-tools` in combination with a private package index.

Now, if I run

```
pip-compile --index-url https://user:password@gitlab.my.tld/api/../packages/pypi/simple
```

This creates a `requirements.txt` with pinned versions that are not existing in the passed private package index.

My expected behaviour would be that all pinned versions in `requirements.txt` should be available on package index or an error is returned. Otherwise, I do not see how I can use `pip-tools` in a private package environment.

Can anyone help and clarify the behaviour?

PS: I have also asked this questions in the github Repository (https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/issues/1546)

Comment: GitLab pypi registry proxies requests to upstream pypi when package doesn't exist in GitLab registry. Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: You are right. This seems to be the issue!

Answer (score 0):

> GitLab pypi registry proxies requests to upstream pypi when package
> doesn't exist in GitLab registry.

*Originally posted by [@richafrank](https://github.com/richafrank) in [#1924 (comment)](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/issues/1546#issuecomment-1008131535).*